# CSS <hr> right aligned next to text

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need a h2 that has a heavy stroke to the right of it. Like so:
[image]

I'm struggling with the best, responsive way to accomplish it. Not to mention that it's in a custom WP theme, so I don't want to create a ton of on page markup that the client will break immediately :)

Comment: Why don't you try using div with (height:2px; widht: 70%; background: red; float:left;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you need is a single element and an [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aafter) pseudo. P.S It's responsive.

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/UzaWIXA)

Explanation: Here, the main part is to use `overflow: hidden;` on the element, and than am creating a virtual element using an `:after` pseudo with `content` property, and am positioning it `absolute` to the parent element which am setting to `relative`

```
<h2>Hello World</h2>

h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}


h2:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  height: 4px;
  background: #f00;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Genuinely Fabulous. +1. Not sure whether OP will like the use of `:after`

Comment: This is about what I was considering adding as an answer (albeit with different layout properties), so +1.

Comment: Very cool! Thanks for taking the time to give a great explanation too! The only potential issue I see is older browser support. This is a genuine question, I thought last I checked pseudo classes weren't supported IE8 or older?

Comment: @bradmagnus `:after` does support IE8, it's `::after` which is supported from IE9 :) and you welcome, also, start supporting your things from IE9 and above, else you will just bloat up your markup as well as CSS for writing supportive styles for IE as well

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thanks for that clarification! I don't know that I'm going to do any support for IE8 or earlier, but I just wanted to be aware of it when talking to the client haha! I started to use :first-child earlier, but need to check that on the VM too.

Comment: @bradmagnus Oh I see, I forgot to add the support reference, sorry for that, I always do, edited my answer with a support link, scroll to the bottom of the page for support table :) and you welcome again

Answer (score 4):

Here you go with a fully responsive solution.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UGFLp/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<h2 class="title">Who we are</h2>
<div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.red{
background:#ff0000;
position:relative;
margin-top:-17px;
height:5px;
z-index:-1;
}

.title{
background:#ffffff;
display:inline;
padding-right:20px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

*PS: You can change the margin/padding accordingly to match your needs as well as media query requirements.*

Comment: @techfoobar - I am sure he is going to use media queries to make his thing responsive, so in that case, whatever resolution change occurs, he needs to change the class properties as per that media query to make that responsive. I hope point justified.

Comment: Yes, still using ems for those values will reduce a lot of work when fine tuning across resolutions.

Comment: Agree, but `ems` will be proportional to `%` values of the inherited elements, so using media queries with the exact resolution parameters, value in px and ems will marginally change. I agree using ems in case of fluid layout, but in responsive, the user generated resolution control shall depend on how the OP executes it. Thx for the inputs - @techfoobar

Comment: So because the title is display:inline it pulls the div up on the line? Does that require a clear:both after to prevent wierdness?

Comment: 1. `display:inline;` does not create any wierdness. 
2. `clear:both;` to clear what?? - @bradmagnus