# Add a margin to the left of a background image

Tags: html, css, less

EDIT: Answer found here [CSS <hr> right aligned next to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582237/css-hr-right-aligned-next-to-text/19582573#19582573) thanks to Mr. Alien

I am trying to make a header title which looks like the following

```
Title -------------------------------------------------
```

I have an image which I am planning to use as the background for it.

But when I add it I am unsure how to position it so it doesn't overlap with the text as it does right now.

It looks like as follows

```
-T-i-t-l-e---------------------------------------
```

HTML

```
<div class="content-header"><p>Check Out</p></div>
```

CSS/LESS

```
.content-header {
width: 90%;
background: url(../images/bulletbg.png) repeat-x center;
margin-top: 10px;
    p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19582573/1542290

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how to position the background image?

Comment: While Mr. Alien's link points to the correct solution, could you type the bullets directly with a web font, perhaps?

Comment: Mr. Alien's link worked for me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is this, you should have a title

```
<h1 style="width: auto">your title</h1><div class="yourbackgroundimage"></div>
```

this way you will not have your title being overrun.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your title and the background in separate divs, then style the divs with "display:inline" or "display:inline-block" - depending on exactly how you want it to behave.

Answer (score 0):

Try the background-position property.

```
background-position: 100px center;
```

[MDN Background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `background-position`.  By default a background will start from the top left but using this will allow you to change the starting position.  You could use it in a number of ways

```
background-position: 20% 0;
```

Or

```
background-position: 10px 0;
```

Play around with it to get it right