# A "hr" of some sort at end of each <article>?

Tags: html, css, article

How do i put a line of about 80% width at the end of my 'article' tags? I only want to edit my css-file and currently it's like this for 'article':

```
article{
    background-color:#FFF;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Do you need something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19582573/1542290

Comment: Oh that was a nice solution. Thanks!